# How do I trigger a click event by clicking on menu items with the url params corresponding to #id on another page

Tags: jquery

Please what do I need to ensure that when I click on the link, the respective section will be opened. The following code is used to add #news to the corresponding a in li elements and when each a[href] is clicked, it directs to the #news section on the new page. 
The first code is appending **#news** to all a[href] from menu and when the menu item is clicked, it will take you to another page with the **#news** and I intended to use the click of the same element (.mega-sub-menu #mega-menu-111-1-2 .mega-sub-menu li > a) to force the section opened.

```
$('.mega-sub-menu #mega-menu-111-1-2 .mega-sub-menu li > a').each(function(){
            var _href = $(this).attr("href"); 
             $(this).attr("href", _href + '#news');
       });
```

But when I did something like this;

```
$('.mega-sub-menu #mega-menu-111-1-2 .mega-sub-menu li > a').click(function(){
         $('#wrapper .row #news').click(); // another page with section id#news
});
```

Comment: Your second code snippet is missing a closing `'` which would create incorrect syntax for jQuery. Please provide a Minimal, Reproducible Example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's quite simple, remove the click event on the element **.mega-sub-menu #mega-menu-111-1-2 .mega-sub-menu li > a**. It's not necessary. You can use window.location.hash as follow;

```
     if(window.location.hash) {
       $('#wrapper .row #news').click();
    }
```

Or

```
$('a[href*="#"]').each(function() {
    $('#wrapper .row #news').click(); //do something 
});
```

But I strongly recommend the first instance.